# How can we improve merge sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, time-complexity

I am trying to modify merge sorting algorithm. As per my modification it looks like it reduce best case and wort case time complexity from O(nlogn) to O (n). I am still working for average time complexity.

As we know that merge sort algorithm is based on divided and conquer method.

**Best Case:**

***Input***: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1. As per merge sort logic we have to split given input into two half group. Continue half process till group size get length 1.
2. After split we go for merge process in fact if number are already sorted. I think we can remove merging process by adding simple one condition

***Condition***: Check if left half of nth element is less then right half of first element. If yes then it is already in sorted no need to compare two half.

eg:

```
L: 1 2 3 4 5       R: 6 7 8 9 10                
if L[4] < R[0]:
    #two half are already in sorted order
else
    #run merge algorithm
```

**Wort Case:**

***Input:*** 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

1. As per merge sort logic we have to split given input into two half group. Continue half process till group size get length 1.
2. It split two half alway be in sort order. In merge process we just reorder two half element by linear process. If you look at reverse sort left and right half. You will find that left group is greater then right group. So here we just need to swap left group to right group.

***Condition:*** Check if left half of 1th element is greater then right half of nth element. If yes then it swap left group and right group

eg:

```
L: 6 7 8 9 10       R: 1 2 3 4 5    
if L[0] > R[4]:
    #two half are already in sorted order
    # swap left and right group value as it is
else
    #run merge algorithm
```

If you have any idea please let us know. Thanks In Advance :).

Comment: Multithreading for big enough N, insertion sort for small enough N.

Comment: Your average case time complexity is O(nlogn) since it's a sorting algorithm that is most effective in terms of complexity class. In addition to Dmitry, some minor things to speed this up (not by much): include a preprocessor that checks if the whole thing is already almost sorted, go with efficient bubble sort in that case. Also, make sure that your algorithm uses efficient structures and accesses them in an efficient way.

Comment: Your worst case (and average) can't be `O(n)` as by the sorting lower bound.

Comment: Dmitry Kuznetsov, I am discussing about merge sort. Aziuth, you are correct that average time complexity is o(nlogn). Thomas Ahle, for worst case it will be O(n), actually it reduce element comparison operation, just swap values.

Comment: It's already been proven that the average case for any comparison sort is O(n log n). You should take the time to write down, on paper, the steps taken by your algorithm. Do it for an array of 5 items, and again for an array of 10 items. I think you'll find that the number of comparisons in the 10-item case will be considerably more than double the number of comparisons in the 5-item case.

Comment: You should also try with the array [10, 1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5], which will not allow you to take advantage of the ordering in your "worst case" reverse sorted example.

Comment: Bottom up merge sort is usually faster than top down merge sort. As for optimization of merge sort, take a look at [timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) .

Answer (score 2):

The worst-case complexity is not really O(*n*), it is still O(*n* log *n*). If you use an array-type structure, then swapping the left and right halves takes O(*n*) time, because you need to move *n* elements around. If you try using a linked list-type structure, then swapping can be done in O(1), but then finding the midpoint takes O(*n*).

Either way, the recurrence formula is still T(*n*) = 2 T(*n* / 2) + O(*n*), which solves to T(*n*) = O(*n* log *n*) according to [the master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).